# Android java read files with Jsoup.parse located on the mac locally on a connected external device

Tags: java, android, macos, file, jsoup

I'm developing an android application.

I need to make my external android device connected to my mac(they are also on the same wifi network), can read a local file which is on the mac.

Do I have to open any doors?

Move the file to a specific dir so it can be seen by the smartphone.

Can you give me a hand?

```java
try {
            values = new getPack("").getInfo();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

```java
class getPack {
    private String baseURL = "file:///Users/nameUser/Desktop/nameDir/file.html";
    private String finalURL = "";
    String thePack;

    public getPack(String idP) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        id = "";
        finalURL = baseURL + id;
        thePack = new GetDirectorInfo().execute().get();
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        return thePack;
    }

    private class GetDirectorInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String text = "";
            try {
                //Document document = Jsoup.connect(finalURL).get();
                File input = new File(finalURL);
                Document document = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
                Element primaryStatus = document.getElementById("primaryStatus");
                text = primaryStatus.text();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return text;
        }
    }
}
```

error:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: Users/nameUser/Desktop/nameDir/file.html: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: No. That is not possible in that way. Make a Windows share of the directory on Mac.